# Remote debugging local Java application with VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I want to debug a JavaEE Webapp on my local machine with VSCode.

The application installation comes with a JRE 7 (integrated in the application folder) and is startet by an .exe file for the application.
This in turn starts a tiny webserver and the JavaEE webapp / Servlet and a portable browser to access that webapp. The installation does not contain java source file classes, only jars with contained class files and resources. There is no docker container involved.

Is it possible to attach VSCode to debug such a scenario?

Comment: You mean debug jars in VS Code? Can you share the project in gthub if it's conveniet? i'll have a try to see if it achievable in vscode.

Comment: No, I can't share it. Jars are part of it. However the application is started via an exe file as described above. It calls the java commands to run the java application.